# Angular $timeout and memory leaks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, timeout

I have found a bunch of different related questions, but I could not find anything that completely clears it up for me, hence my question. I am trying to determine when/if a $timeout within a directive leaks memory when the scope is destroyed. In each of the cases below, could someone tell me if the timeout will leak or not when the scope is destroyed.

Case 1: The timeout is executed in the next event loop, or with a delay but the delay has expired before the scope is destroyed

Case 1A: The timer promise does not have a reference

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.a = 2;
});
```

Case 1B: The timer promise reference is stored in a variable in the controller

```
var timerPromise;
timerPromise = $timeout(function(){
  $scope.a = 2;
});
```

Case 1C: The timer promise reference is stored on the scope

```
$scope.timerPromise = $timeout(function(){
  $scope.a = 2;
});
```

Case 2:
The timeout is executed after a delay, and the delay has not expired before the scope is destroyed

Case 2A: The timer promise does not have a reference

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.a = 2;
}, 10000);
```

Case 2B: The timer promise reference is stored in a variable in the controller

```
var timerPromise;
timerPromise = $timeout(function(){
  $scope.a = 2;
}, 10000);
```

Case 2C: The timer promise reference is stored on the scope

```
$scope.timerPromise = $timeout(function(){
  $scope.a = 2;
}, 10000);
```

Case 3: The timer is called again before the timer gets executed

// Say that the somefunc is called many times in the 10 seconds

```
function somefunc() {
    $scope.timerPromise = $timeout(function(){
      $scope.a = 2;
    }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? $scope will be cleared up on garbage collection but not for the next 10 seconds at least.

Comment: I edited the question - essentially I am trying to determine if there is a memory leak due to the timeout in any of the cases above once the scope is destroyed.

Comment: No, there's no memory leak.

Comment: Thank you. I added case 3 as well, could you tell me if there is a memory leak in case 3?

Comment: Nope.  `$rootScope.foo = $scope` causes memory leak, so does `window.foo = $scope`. Memory leaks don't come out of nowhere (actually, they do in trashy browsers, but in this case they don't have a reasonable explanation). If a reference to removed object isn't saved in persistent object, it is garbage collected. If it is saved, it leaks. Any way, it is a good habit to do `if ($scope.timerPromise) $scope.timerPromise.cancel()` on directive destroy.